# Encoding/Decoding video with H264

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, encoding, h.264

I'm writing an iOS app that I plan on uploading to the App Store.

The app is a video chat app, and I was thinking about using Apples Hardware accelerated way to encode/decode the stream I want to send, However from my understanding this implementation is not stream oriented, which means that I will get the header in the end of the file.

I basically have a few questions.

1. Can I write my own implementation, If anyone can point towards any articles about that would be great.
2. If I write my own implementation, can I use the hardware accelerated encoding/decoding?
3. .If I write my own implementation would I need to pay licensing fees?
4. Is there any other codecs I can use that are stream oriented? Preferably once's that I don't have to license.

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, if you're planning on making it like chat roulette, or a random video chatting service, apple will not accept those. Just a piece of information to save you the trouble of making this app, if that's how it will go down ;)

As for your question, will you be doing P2P video chatting? or will it go through a server?

I have a good amount of info on P2P video chatting.

Comment: @MichaelKing Well, this isn't exactly chatroulette, You are talking about them getting iChatr down is that correct? we have a few things done differently, Can you please share your experience, I want it to be P2P, I'm also looking for a coder(for a nice sum) if that interest you.